# Oculus Rift VR - Samples projects error

Tags: c++, virtual-reality, oculus

I downloaded the SDK from Oculus Rift website, and I'm trying to run the projects 
on the samples folder. 
When I build the project I'm getting an error that says

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open open include file: 'd3dcompiler.h' : no such file or directory.
```

although they add the lib files in the linker. 
anyone else got this errors on their samples projects?

Comment: Looks like a dependency on the [DirectX development kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6812). Do you have that installed?

Comment: I installed windows SDK from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279 it should contain the DirectX no?

Comment: That's the SDK for developing general Windows software. Most people don't need DirectX to develop apps, and it's not included.

Comment: thanks, but you could to write this as an answer, and I was accept this :) thanks a lot Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`d3dcompiler.h`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607324(v=vs.85).aspx) is part of the [DirectX development kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6812). You need to have it installed and either on your project path or your tool's path.

The header will be on the include path but you may need to link against a library, too.

You can add it using:

```
comment(lib, "D3dcompiler.lib")
```

See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh968107(v=vs.85).aspx).

The documentation above says you need `D3dcompiler_xx.dll`